# Testing Block output

Tags: magento-2.1, testing, integration-test

I made a customization to the TopMenu and want to run an integration test.

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * Check if menu items have the right URL
 */
public function testUrlInMenu()
{
    \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')
        ->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
    \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(
        'Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface'
    )->setDesignTheme(
        'Magento/blank'
    );

    /**
     * @var $layout \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    $layout = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface::class
    );

    $block = $layout->addBlock(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::class, 'test');

    $result = $block->toHtml();
    $this->assertContains('http://localhost/index.php/', $result);
}
```

This test fails with

```
BadMethodCallException : Missing required argument $debugHintsPath of Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Plugin\DebugHints.
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:45
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:82
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:71
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:233
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:151
/foo/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngineFactory/Interceptor.php:26
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEnginePool.php:44
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:254
/foo/var/generation/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Topmenu/Interceptor.php:167
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:279
/foo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:659
/foo/var/generation/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Topmenu/Interceptor.php:479
/foo/vendor/mestrona/magento-module-categoryredirect/Test/Integration/CatalogAttributesTest.php:110
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debugHintsPath is not defined for global aria. 
Can you try add `@magentoAppArea frontend` to you test? I hope it will resolve problem.